# C# unit test results in SonarQube 5.6

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, msbuild, sonarqube

Environment : SonarQube 5.6 - SonarQube Runner 2.4 - MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-2.0 - TFS 2015 - C#6

I've a Visual Studio 2015 solution with C# 6 projects and unit tests. On my TFS 2015 server, I define a build (task-based, not xaml).  On my build, I've added the following steps :
 - SonarQube for MSBuild - Begin Analysis.
 - Visual Studio Test
 - SonarQube for MSBuild - End Analysis.

Everything run fine (build, unit tests execution, code coverage, analysis results based on SonarLint, ... except that I don't see the tests results in the Sonar report (code coverage is there !).

I've tried to add some parameters :
- begin analysis : I've added : /d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=../TestResults/*.trx
- vstests console : /Logger:trx

In the end analysis logs, I see this :

Attempting to locate a test results (.trx) file...
Located a test results file: E:\agent_work\3\TestResults\tests_results_2016-06-23 14_07_22.trx
Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpUnitTestResultsProvider$CSharpUnitTestResultsImportSensor
Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpUnitTestResultsProvider$CSharpUnitTestResultsImportSensor (done) | time=0ms

Any idea why I see always Unit tests=0 in the Sonar report ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide full path to the .trx file. With below changes in begin analysis and try it again.

**Change**

```
/d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=../TestResults/*.trx
```

**To**

```
 /d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=../TestResults/Mytest.trx
```

Comment: The output file name of the TFS test runner console cannot be enforced.  It contains the date end time.  I've added an intermediate task to rename any trx file to testsresults.trx.  I've now the following error : 
Located a test results file: E:\agent\_work\3\TestResults\testresults.trx
Post-processing succeeded.
##[error]Unexpected exit code received from batch file: 255
##[warning]Could not find the summary report file E:\agent\_work\3\.sonarqube\out\summary.md